# Tensorflow - Works on cpu returns cost as nan on gpu

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, nan

Can anyone explain and or correct me as to why this produces Nan Loss on GPU and works fine on CPU? On GPU the output of the first calculation of c is fine but after the first it becomes nan and remains that way.

It was working on the GPU before I put in the producer consumer threads into the program.

```
  class Consumer:
        def __init__(self,maximum,sess,optimizer,cost):

            self.nextTime=1
            self.max=maximum
            self.i=0
            self.sess=sess
            self.optimizer=optimizer
            self.cost=cost
        def run(self):
            global qfeatures,finishedflag,qlabels,errorcount,epoch_loss
            while (self.i<(self.max-errorcount)):
                if(self.nextTime<time.clock() and not qfeatures.empty()):
                    if(self.i/100).is_integer():
                        print('remove'+str(self.i))
                        print(epoch_loss)
                    batch_x=qfeatures.get()
                    batch_y=qlabels.get()
                    #print('Removing')
                    batch_x=np.array(batch_x)
                    batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size,n_chunks,chunk_size))
                    _, c = self.sess.run([self.optimizer, self.cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,y: np.array(batch_y)})
                    if math.isnan(c):
                        sys.exit('nan error')

                    epoch_loss += c
                    print(epoch_loss)
                    self.nextTime+=(random.random()*2)/100
                    self.i+=1

            finishedflag=1
            print('finished out')
```

The full code can also be found in [this GitHub Repository](https://github.com/JasonPrendergast/ThreadedTraining).

Comment: I'm unsure as to why the Cuda tag has been removed as the code is not working on the GPU which is a Cuda GPU. Also, as far as I'm aware Tensorflow can only be ran on a Cuda GPU. Also I suspect it might be cuDNN related.

Comment: Have you tried using the tensorflow debugger to set a breakpoint and find out which op is the first to return a NaN and what were its inputs?

Comment: The OP type is ApplyAdam, tensor_name is Adam/update_rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/ApplyAdam:0

As shown here:
http://tinypic.com/r/34j6f7n/9

And here is the tensor:
http://tinypic.com/r/2qko482/9

Comment: I don't see NaNs in it. ApplyAdam takes many inputs.

Comment: The Nan is the cost output. The in going tensor is not NaN, this is checked with if not all(v== 0 for v in line_x): in the producer class. This prevents any empty tensors from entering the queue for the consumer. It works on the CPU but not on the GPU.

Comment: So cost shouldn't be produced by applyadam at all. tfdbg seems to be showing that the first NaN is not actually the cost but the weights of your model after adam is updated. Maybe the GPU variables are not being initialized correctly?

Comment: Someone on the facebook group "Artificial Intelligence & Deep Learning" suggested it is the softmax with logits which is causing the problem. The result is larger than a 32 float. Still no closer to solving it. What can I replace softmax with to test?

Comment: Please keep the code *in* the question itself, noone has time to look through every file of your github repo. Read more at [mcve].

Comment: Same issue here. My program returns Nan on CPU only, but good for GPU...